# Beginner Drush question. Can't get Drush to do anything!

Tags: drush

I can't get Drush to do much.  I can connect to my site by typing `cd` and then dragging my files to the terminal window in OSX using Acquia DevDesktop. My overall goal is to create a sub theme of Omega.

When I type `drush omega-wizard` I get:

> The drush command 'omega-wizard' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions. [error]
>
> Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.         [error]
>
> Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
>
> - bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a
>     configured database. In this case you can select another site with a
>     working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri
>     parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for
>     details.
> - connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be
>     wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See
>     http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.

I think this means that I haven't shown Drush where the settings file is.  For the life of me, I'm not able to do that.  Normally, I would do something like:

```
cd sites/nameofsite.localhost
```

or

```
cd site/nameoffolder.localhost
```

I've tried every iteration of this command: with the localhost, without the localhost, different folder names, etc.  I always get "No such file or directory".  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  What does Drush need me to tell it?

Thanks so much in advance,

Jason

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this a two step process?  The first step I show Drush where my site is.  I have no problem with that. After I do this I can get Drush to do some stuff.  The problem begins when I need to download a module or whatever.  That's the 2nd step. I end up with an error that states that the command could not be found, or no such file or directory.  That's because I need to show it my settings file, I believe.  I've tried so many different folder configurations and can't seem to get it right.  Can anyone tell me exactly what it should look like?

Comment: In the past, I've used cd sites/nameofsite.localhost, and that worked.  I can't seem to get it to work with that.  Also, Drush knows what my Drupal root is (/Users/jasonmaier/Sites/devdesktop/drupa 
                           l-7.36 ).  Why can't it find my setting file?

Comment: Thanks so much Free Radical!  I tried cd /Users/jasonmaier/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-7.36/sites/default/settings.php , and got "not a directory". what else should I try?

Comment: I knew that.  So, I tried it with no luck.  I still can't get drush omega-wizard to run.  I get the "The drush command 'omega-wizard' could not be found" etc.

Comment: Sorry Free Radical.  The etc. part is the bootstrap part.  Here is the full error:  The drush command 'omega-wizard' could not be found.  Run `drush     [error]
cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have
installed new extensions.
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.         [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a
configured database. In this case you can select another site with a
working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri
parameter on the command

Comment: ...line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for
details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be
wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See
http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.

Drush was attempting to connect to: 
 Drupal version         :  7.36                                     
 Site URI               :  http://default                           
 Default theme          :  garland                                  
 Administration theme   :  garland

Comment: PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php                             
 PHP configuration      :                                           
 PHP OS                 :  Darwin                                   
 Drush version          :  7.0-dev                                  
 Drush configuration    :                                           
 Drush alias files      :                                           
 Drupal root            :  /Users/jasonmaier/Sites/devdesktop/drupa 
                           l-7.36

Comment: Site path              :  sites/default                            
 File directory path    :  sites/default/files

Comment: Sorry Free Radical!  I wish I could put it all in one post.  But there's a limit as to how many characters in a single post.

Comment: Learn to use the site!  Look below your *question*.  There is a button - "edit".  Press it.  Then put all the relevant stuff into the body of the question. Delete stuff that is no longer relevant.  Then click "Save edits". (There is no limit to how many characters there can be in the question.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a known problem of using **Drush** with **DevDesktop** on **MacOSX**.

**Quick fix**

Instead of running drush like this:

```
$ drush status
```

Run it like this:

```
$ DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR="$HOME/.acquia/DevDesktop/DrupalSettings" drush status
```

**Permanent fix**

Everything is explained in this article:
http://btmash.com/article/2015-03-24/using-dev-desktop-composer-drush

**Why is it happenenig?**

Acquia DevDesktop keeps all credentials in a specific folder and let PHP have access to that location via a $_SERVER variable called `$_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR']`. This variable is provided by Apache and PHP only sees it is run by Apache. But when you use Drush, PHP is called directly and that variable does not exists anymore and Drush cannot find the database credentials.